# Select last observed value from a column in a data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a df like this:

```
ColumnA             ColumnB
TCK01/TCK02/TCK03   date1
TCK04               date2
TCK05/TCK06         date3
```

I want to sum the two columns but only keeping the last observed value (or if there is only one keep it) in the ColumnA and adding a "-" between the values, to get something like this:

```
ColumnA             ColumnB     Column AB
TCK01/TCK02/TCK03   date1       TCK03-date1
TCK04               date2       TCK04-date2
TCK05/TCK06         date3       TCK06-date3
```

Comment: `df['ColumnA'].str.split('/').str[0] + '-' + df['ColumnB']`

Comment: Thanks for the aswer but in this way the value from ColumnA isn't the last observed because you are using str[0], if the values in column A were the same lenght this will work perefectly, but since I have different lenghts this is not working. If I choose 1 insted of 0 it will store the second value in the AB column for the first and the third rows but in the second row I have only one value in the column A, so this solution will display a NaN in the AB column.

Comment: Replace 0 by -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex based Solution:

```
df['Column AB'] = df['ColumnA'].str.extract(r'(T[^\/]+)$')[0] + '-' + df['ColumnB']
```

---

**df:**

```
    ColumnA             ColumnB Column AB
0   TCK01/TCK02/TCK03   date1   TCK03-date1
1   TCK04               date2   TCK04-date2
2   TCK05/TCK06         date3   TCK06-date3
```

For regex explanation: https://regex101.com/r/TwslQu/1

Comment: It worked perfectly fine! just what I was looking for. Thank you @Pygirl